# How do i find the difference in 2 dates (in days) when using m-d-Y format?

Tags: php, date, strtotime, datediff

I need something like this

```
$today = date("m-d-Y");
$otherdate = "05-03-2013";

//Some math here

//echo the difference between the two dates in days
```

I've tried using strtotime but it doesn't work correctly and usually says something like the difference was somewhere around 15k days (which obviously isn't right)

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try [`diff()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method of `DateTime`:

```
$now  = new DateTime();
$then = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '05-03-2013');

$interval = $now->diff($then);

$days = $interval->format('%a days');
```

Comment: I was just wondering, that works when i use a direct string like 

$then = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '05-03-2013');

but when i use


 $anotherdate = $row['laston'];
 $then = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', $anotherdate);

it does not work...

Comment: @Douglas Mckee , sholud be working. Please, check string for consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for `Y-m-d` format date

```
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d")); // or your date as well
$otherdate = strtotime("2013-05-03");
$datediff = $now - $otherdate;
echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24)). "Days";
```

Comment: please reconsider your answer because if You use it when you change your clock (winter to summer time) there will be wrong result. Try `$now = strtotime("2013-04-01");` and `$otherdate = strtotime("2013-03-30");`

Answer (score 0):

## **PHP 5.3+**

```
$b_date1 = new DateTime($date);
$today1 = new DateTime($today);
$interval = date_diff($today1,$b_date1);
```

PHP version less than 5.2

## **Or**

```
function date_diff1($date1, $date2) { 
    $current = $date1; 
    $datetime2 = date_create($date2); 
    $count = 0; 
    while(date_create($current) < $datetime2){ 
        $current = gmdate("Y-m-d", strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($current))); 
        $count++; 
    } 
    return $count; 
}
```